# the meaning of 'lavish' here

Tags: word-meaning

> Irwin Shubert was nineteen, a tall bronzed boy with curly black hair,
>   sleepy black eyes, and a mouth too ***lavish*** for his face.
>
> -The Apprenticeship of Duddy Kravitz by Mordecai Richler -

Does 'lavish' here mean 'big'?

Comment: Big, yes, but with the added connotations of "lavish", which is normally used of rooms very grandly decorated, or of feasts with a great number of dishes, or of other kinds of extravagance. We sometimes use the phrase "too generous" in the same way.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo:    like the mouth Mick Jagger has?

Comment: MJ certainly uses it lavishly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are right. His mouth was too big or bright, or both big and bright for his face.